# Can I get error index with bulk_create/bulk_update?

Tags: django

I'm using `bulk_create` method to insert data from an Excel sheet to db. This data can be incorrect (ex: cell contains "Hello World" when it should be an integer) and I'd like to return user thorough information error.

Currently, bulk_create raises a ValueError, ex:  `Field 'some_integer_field' expected a number but got 'Hello World'.`

Is it possible to get more details about this error, something like : `**Line 4** - Field 'some_integer_field' expected a number but got 'Hello World'.` without saving each object individually ? Does it even make sense since `bulk_create` produces a single transaction ?

I'm running Django 4.1.3 with PostgreSQL 12. 
My code looks like `self.MyModel.bulk_create(self.objects_to_create)`

Comment: Why not run this data through serializer first, print errors/row on validation error and skip this object and pass valid data to object instance which will be then used in bulk_create?

Comment: You mean through DRF serializer ? If so I don't think its much more efficient than saving each objects individualy but I'll give it a try.

Comment: Yes, but don't save it through serializer, just get this serialized data, pass it to object, like so: ExampleModelObject(**serialized_data.validated_data) and add this not saved instance to list of objects which then will be saved in bulk

Comment: any success in trying to fix it?

Comment: I've tried it but it's not efficient and requires DRF, I'd rather stick with pure Django.